# com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I was trying to write a file to a GCP bucket from an application that runs in a google compute engine instance,

```
  public void writeToGCS(String bucketName, String bucketPath, String objectName, String content) {
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("my project id").build().getService();
    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, bucketPath + "/" + objectName);
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
    storage.create(blobInfo, content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  }
```

When I called this method and supplied bucket name, path and file content, I got the error:

```
 com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException.translate(StorageException.java:170)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:329)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.open(HttpStorageRpc.java:1062)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.ResumableMedia.lambda$startUploadForBlobInfo$0(ResumableMedia.java:40)
        at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:103)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.Retrying.run(Retrying.java:65)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.ResumableMedia.lambda$startUploadForBlobInfo$1(ResumableMedia.java:34)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.writer(StorageImpl.java:691)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.createFrom(StorageImpl.java:289)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.createFrom(StorageImpl.java:280)
```

I would expect the code to write a file